# Accessing bucket from dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, gcsfuse

I'm trying to access data stored in a Google storage bucket from a Dataproc cluster. However thus far, even if I declare my bucket files public, my jobs exit with an error that the file does not exist. I considering trying to mount the bucket to a folder in my cluster machines. To this end, I've successfully installed the gcsfuse package in my initialization script and when I ssh in to the cluster, I am able to successfully use the gcsfuse to add files to my root folder. However when I then exit ssh, my job still claims that the local folder doesn't exist. How can I address this issue to access files in a public bucket from my Dataproc cluster?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you want to access GCS in Hadoop/Spark job?
Can you access you bucket using command line tools `gsutil ls gs://<BUCKET>` and `hadoop fs -ls gs://<BUCKET>` from inside Dataproc VM? If no, may you post error that you receive?

Comment: @rajjo - were you able to solve this issue ? i'm getting same similar issue - refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238888/gcp-dataproc-job-not-finding-ssl-pem-certs-stored-in-buckets

Answer (score 3):

On Dataproc using Spark or Hadoop, the canonical way to access GCS is via the GCS connector for Hadoop. In Spark and Hadoop jobs, you should be able to access GCS as `gs://[bucket]/[some/object/path]`.

This method should work for reading input to jobs via SparkContext methods, Hadoop MapReduce FileInputFormat subclasses, and via the Hadoop FileSystem APIs.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, if you submit your job like this, the file should be accessible inside your Dataproc job:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster cluster_name \
--region europe-west1 \
--class your_java_class \
--jars your_jars \
--files gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv
```

This way '`file_name.csv`' can be accessed by the code inside your job and you don't have to do anything extra. I think however that this way the file(s) actually get physically copied to your machines. This works for me, as I only need small files. If you want to actually keep the files in your bucket and access them directly, then perhaps the Hadoop approach is better.

I think this is much easier to do from the script rather form the UI console, as I haven't managed to get it to work via the UI console.